# How can solar eclipse magnify the moons effects?

Tags: planets, moons, radiation

The moon is made up of a substance called warpstone. This rock is solidified Mana compressed into physical form. Pieces of the moon will sometimes fall to earth, which contain magical properties and are used in spells. Although powerful, it is very unstable and radioactive. Special precautions must be made when working with the stone, lest it cause mutations within the individual.

Occasionally, an event known as a solar eclipse occurs, when the moon, sun, and earth align with each other. During this event, the magical power of witches increase. However, It is advised that pregnant women remain inside during the event to avoid exposing their unborn child to danger. Developing babies caught in the eclipse have an increased likeliness of being stillborn or born with various deformities and mutations. Exposure to the event increases the chances 70%, but leave regular individuals unaffected.

Common sense leads one to infer that the moons radioactive effects are augmented during a solar eclipse. However, nobody can explain why this happens during this event, but remain normal during other times of the year, or why only unborn children are in danger while anyone else remains unaffected. How can I explain these effects?

Answer (score 3):

Oh, it is very simple: solar neutrino (or just "solar magic") radiation becomes "corrupted" with moon magic. Moon (and actually everything, exept blackholes) is transparent to this radiation. So moonshadow is a danger zone for pregnant astranouts and , during eclipse, for everyone happen to be on the way of its shadow.

It just like watching the Sun through bloody grim glass...

Answer (score 1):

**Magic Alignment**

Moon rocks cannot fall to Earth under normal circumstances. This is because the moon is a gravity well, and thus to 'fall to Earth', the rock has to first clear the moon's gravitational pull and then alter it's orbit until it's on trajectory to land on Earth, and somehow not burn up in the atmosphere. Since there's no way to explain this conventionally, obviously the fact that the moon is magical is the reason why this happens. In fact, there's probably hundreds of thousands of wild mana reactions on the surface of the moon at any given point in time, and the resultant effects cause the moon rocks to fall to Earth.

Oh, also the Sun is magical, or at the very least it's powerful rays affect magic when not diffused through the thick atmosphere on Earth. Why? Because that makes things easier for us and once we have a magic moon, a magic sun is within the realm of possibility.

Thus, when the Sun directly hit the Moon, it causes a weird reaction known as 'The Alignment Reaction' or TAR for short, which projects TAR rays. Why? Well, obviously because the very core of the moon is made of a super-condensed mana crystal, of course. But this only happens on the direct line between the Sun and the center of the moon, so whenever there isn't an eclipse, that line isn't pointed at Earth. But when there is - the TAR effect.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the lunar radiation during an eclipse more dangerous to an unborn child that to a normal being?

My thoughts on this are that an unborn being is still under quite a bit of flux and therefore is easy to change. Therefore the chaotic lunar radiation can change these beings more easily. Normal (already born) beings still change, but at a slower rate. The beings are more resistant to such short-lived chaotic change.